# Silverlight Guidance - How to do this from Telerik? (reference attached image)

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I really like a certain Silverlight feature that I've seen in a couple of sites.  I would like to know what this "concept(s)" is/are so I can do more research and implemented it on my own.  If you see the attached image, I like those expandable sections, reference (1) and (2) sections.  They are circled in red and the features that I like are green and expandable.

For a live demo: http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#DataPager/FirstLook

[image]

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I'm a fan of the telerik SL controls too. I would suggest you register for their forums and just ask them directly how they did it - they are a good bunch of guys, i think you'll find them more than helpful.

Comment: +1 slugster. 
Fan of Telerik :) Asking in their forum would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks slugster and Avatar - that's true and thought of it as soon as I posted here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the screenshot, it's just a collapsible pane. Such a control would have an API allowing two pieces of child content to be supplied, an orientation to be set (horizontal/vertical), and perhaps a collapse direction (left/right or up/down).

The control's template would place each piece of content alongside the other with a separator in between. Clicking the separator would collapse one piece of content in the chosen direction, thus giving the other piece of content more room.